# ASPX markup. Referencing a connection string from a key value in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, appsettings

In my web.config I have a connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="MyWebAppCS" connectionString="Data Source=.\ ...>
```

I also have a AppSettings key which points to the name.

```
<add key="CSName" value="MyWebAppCS" />
```

On all the aspx pages, at the moment the connection strings for SqlDataSources are hard coded to the connection string name.

```
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyWebAppCS %>"
```

Is it possible to use the inline code to reference the connection string via the AppSettings key - something like

```
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AppSettings:CSName %>"
```

I've been trying different snytax combinations but can't find anything that works. Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, but not using `<%$`, instead set it in a `<script runat="server">` or ideally, your code-behind class.

Comment: Also, _why on earth_ are you using WebForms in 2021? It's been obsolete for 13 years now and generates utterly atrocious HTML markup.

Comment: It's a legacy app I'm trying to sort. Did consider migrating it to razor but it would be a big job...